# Is there a program that will monitor a txt file and print it when ever it is updated automaticly?

Tags: windows-7, printing, ms-dos

Client is using a very old DOS program that I can not get to directly print. I can get it to write out to a txt file though. I know about PrintFile but it will only print the file once and won't print again if the txt file gets updated.

This is a long shot but the DOS program I am working with is TeleMagic v14. If you know how to get usb/parallel printer to print while running win 7 that would take care of the problem as well.

Comment: Long story short the writing to a file idea is not going to work with this client. Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it not have a print option at all, or is it looking to only print to a "physical" lpt port? If that's the case, you may be able to get it to print to a shared printer using the net use command. Something like net use lpt1: \hostname\printer

Comment: It has an option to print to lpt1 lpt2, etc. With lpt1 chosen nothing happens. The printer is currently on lpt1.

Comment: not sure if this works on win7 but try "print /d:lpt1 file.txt" what happens?

Comment: the printer prints the file. I can get the printer to print fine in windows whether its on usb or lpt.

Comment: must be writing directly to the hardware if thats the case you'll need to create a wmi async event to monitor for file creation.  I'll try to find some code for you.